# Getting an error property length cannot be assisgned to never

Tags: javascript, html

He is my code, I have a name array coming from another js file, it is an array:

```
texthtml += '<div class="top-row-pinned-input">';
texthtml += '<select class="top-row-pinned-field" value="'+colDef.field+'" id="air-country-' + colDef.field + '" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">';
for (let i = 0; i < '+name+'.length; i++) {
    texthtml += '<option value="name[i]">name[i]</option>';
}
texthtml += '</select>';
texthtml += '</div>';
```

I need to iterate it, create a DOM select element and display its values in dropdown.

Can you please assist

Comment: Please add your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your name parameter is considered as string, try this

```
 texthtml += '<div class="top-row-pinned-input">';
 texthtml += '<select class="top-row-pinned-field" value="'+colDef.field+'" id="air-country-' + colDef.field + '" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">';
 for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
     texthtml += '<option value="name[i]">name[i]</option>';
 }
 texthtml += '</select>';
 texthtml += '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
 for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
          texthtml += '<option value="'+name[i]+'">'+name[i]+'</option>';
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
  texthtml += '<option value="'+name[i]+'">'+name[i]+'</option>';
  }
```

Above code maybe help you.

Answer (score 0):

ES6:

```
name.map(item => texthtml += '<option value="'+item +'">'+item+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping incorrectly on a string rather than the actual `name` array. Also you should change `name` to something like `nameArr`.

Try This :

```
texthtml += '<div class="top-row-pinned-input">';
texthtml += '<select class="top-row-pinned-field" value="'+colDef.field+'" id="air-country-' + colDef.field + '" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">';
for (let i = 0; i < nameArr.length ; i++) {
    texthtml += '<option value="'+nameArr[i]+'">'+nameArr[i]+'</option>';
}
texthtml += '</select>';
texthtml += '</div>';
```